# Proof that stochastic process on infinite graph ends in finite step.

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes

**Infinite Graph**

Let $G$ be an infinite graph that is constructed this way: start with two unconnected nodes $v_1$ and $u_1$. We call this "level 1".

Create two more unconnected nodes $v_2$ and $u_2$. Connect $v_1$ to both of them with directed edges pointing from $v_1$ to $v_2$, and from $v_1$ to $u_2$ respectively. Then, connect $u_1$ to both of them using directed edges in the same way. This is "level 2".

Repeat this process. At level $n$, nodes $v_n$ and $u_n$ are both connected to the each of the next two nodes $v_{n+1}$ and $u_{n+1}$. This results in an infinite connected graph.

**Stochastic Process**

We define a discrete time process heuristically on this graph. $v_1$ and $u_1$ are initially "infected". This infection only last for one time period. We start at $t = 0$.

At each time step, infected nodes have an independent probability $p$ of passing the infection to their neighbors (infected node must have a directed edge to the target for the target to be a neighbor). If this happens, the neighbor is infected for one time period.

E.g. $v_1$ is connected to $v_2$ and $u_2$. $v_1$ is infected initially. At time $t=0$, $v_1$ has a probability $p$ of infecting its neighbors $v_2$ and $u_2$. Suppose it successfully infects $v_2$, and $u_2$ is never infected by any of its predecessor. At $t=1$, $v_1$ and $u_1$ stops being infectious. And $v_2$ is infectious.

This process is repeated for each level. If a node is infected twice, it is still just "infected", there is no special meaning to a double infection.

**Conjecture**

This process ends with probability $1$ after a finite number of steps.

How do I prove this? My attempt: The probability that the infection on one level is passed onto the next level is $q = 1 - (1-p)^4 = $ probability that all $4$ attempts to infect fails. For the infection to reach the $k$th level, the probability is $q^k$ and this tends to zero as $k$ tends to infinity?

Comment: First question: what is the probability that $v_2$ is infected at time $t=1$?

Comment: There are two chances for $v_2$ to be infected. Either by $v_1$ or $u_1$. If both misses, $v_2$ is not infected, with probability $(1-p)^2$. So probability that $v_2$ is infected is $1 - (1-p)^2$?

Comment: I don't know - it depends on how you define the contagion. Do I understand correctly: if $x$ has $n\in[0;4]$ infected neighbors, then the probability that $x$ will not be infected is $(1-p)^n$? At the same time, if $y$ is infected, then any of its neighbors can get the infection independently? (that is, if $y$ infects $x$ it can still infect $z$?)

Comment: Yes to both. However, since the infection lasts for only 1 time period, each node can only have up to 2 infected neighbors at any time. Sorry. I added these details back into the question.

Comment: Why not $4$? Say, at time $1$ only $v_2$ is infected, and at time $2$ it infects $v_1,u_1,v_3,u_3$ which makes $v_2$ having $4$ infected neighbors.

Comment: Oh dear. Yes there is another mistake. The infection is only passed in one direction from level $n$ to $n+1$ and not backwards to $n-1$. Updating the question to include directed edges. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you direct the edges then the problem becomes trivial.

Assume inductively that at time $i$ the only nodes that might be infected are $u_i$ and $v_i$.

Then at time $i+1$ nodes $u_{i+1}$ and $v_{i+1}$ may become infected by $u_i$ and $v_i$, but $u_i$ and $v_i$ become cured, and there is no way of reinfecting them from below.

Thus your argument is correct, and the probability that the process is alive at time $i$ is at most $q^i$.

Now, for any natural number $n$, if the process does not terminate after a finite number of levels, then the process much reach level $n$.

Therefore the probablity that the process does not terminate is less than or equal to the probability that the process reaches level $n$.

So if $A$ is the event that the process survives indefinitely we have
$$0\leq\mathbb P(A) \leq q^n$$for every $n\in\mathbb N$. Therefore we must have $\mathbb P(A) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. What I am confused about is that the probability for the infection to reach level $k$ is $q^k$, which is always positive and never $0$ for all $k$. So, is it wrong to say the process ends in a finite number of levels with probability $1$? Since if $l$ is the finite number, the probability of the process going to the $l+1$ level is $q^{l+1}>0$?

Comment: @Legendre The process ends after a finite number of levels with probability one.  I've expanded that part of the argument.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! What I misunderstood "process ends after finite number of steps" to mean that the process must end at a certain level $l$. But in fact, the finite step/level that the process ends can be any level from $1,2,3,...$. If any of these happen, the process ends in finite steps.